# Unable to install wkhtmltopdf on Heroku: The command '/bin/sh -c curl return a non-zero code: 6

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, wkhtmltopdf

This is my Dockerfile; while i am able to run it on localhost when i try to build on Heroku i got the error:
The command '/bin/sh -c curl "https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz" -L -o "wkhtmltopdf.tar.xz"' returned a non-zero code: 6

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
MAINTAINER Giovanni Bianciardi <giovannibiancardi@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y \
  build-essential libpq-dev --no-install-recommends

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
  curl \
  libxrender1 \
  libfontconfig \
  libxtst6 \
  xz-utils

RUN curl "https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz" -L -o "wkhtmltopdf.tar.xz"
RUN tar Jxvf wkhtmltopdf.tar.xz

RUN mv wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
ENTRYPOINT ["wkhtmltopdf"]
```

Comment: no one can help?

Answer (score 1):

I solved by just installing another release of wkhtmltopdf

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
MAINTAINER Giovanni Bianciardi <giovannibiancardi@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y \
  build-essential libpq-dev --no-install-recommends

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
  wget \
  curl \
  libxrender1 \
  libfontconfig \
  libxtst6 \
  xz-utils


RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
RUN tar vxf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
RUN cp wkhtmltox/bin/wk* /usr/local/bin/
```